# What is the meaning of '<==>' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spaceship-operator

What is the meaning of '<==>' in Ruby?

Example: The code comes from the following class that compares numbers in the format `x.x.x`,

```
def <==>(other)
    # Some code here
end
```

The following code comes from this class that orders numbers like `x.x.x`,

```
class Version

    attr_reader :fst, :snd, :trd
    def initialize(version="")
        v = version.split(".")
        @fst = v[0].to_i
        @snd = v[1].to_i
        @trd = v[2].to_i
    end

    def <=>(other)
        return @fst <=> other.fst if ((@fst <=> other.fst) != 0)
        return @snd <=> other.snd if ((@snd <=> other.snd) != 0)
        return @trd <=> other.trd if ((@trd <=> other.trd) != 0)
    end

    def self.sort
        self.sort!{|a,b| a <=> b}
    end

    def to_s
        @sorted = @fst.to_s + "." + @snd.to_s + "." + @trd.to_s
        #Puts out "#{@sorted}".
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that is valid code...

Comment: Now I'm wondering [why it's only one equals sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508338/why-does-the-spaceship-operator-have-only-one-equal-sign-in-it).

Answer (score 12):

That is the [spaceship operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator). However, it is actually `<=>` (not `<==>`).

Although that is not its official name, I'm sure, it's the most commonly used name for that operator. It is a comparison operator where

- If other is less than self, return 1,
- If other is equal to self, return 0
- If other is greater than self, return -1

It is a powerful operator in that by just implementing this you can do sorting of your own type and participate in a lot of other niceties, like the Enumerable mixin.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just try it out? By just typing in the code you posted, it is trivial to see for yourself that it doesn't mean anything, since `<==>` is not a valid method name in Ruby. The code you posted will just raise a `SyntaxError`.