# Why does the spaceship operator have only one equal sign in it?

Tags: ruby, perl, spaceship-operator

Why was the spaceship operator `<=>` chosen to have one equal sign rather than two? Is this seen as inconsistent with one equal sign usually meaning assignment, and two meaning comparison?

Comment: canceling out the -1. people can be so unnecessarily mean here, it's a perfectly valid question, to a Forth programmer anyway.

Comment: [Wikipedia's answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator) can shed more light on it but it's pretty dry reading and is much the same as Perl's docs about it. Larry Wall, having some training in linguistics, might have a more valid reason but I haven't ever seen it documented beyond Perl's docs.

Personally, after too many years dealing with seemingly arbitrary decisions for whatever operator choice they inflict on us in languages, I've given up and just accept them for whatever they are. Calling it the "spaceship operator" makes it fun.

Comment: It could be worse, it could have been `</==/>`

Comment: Why did the double horizontal bar in the mathematical "greater/less than or equal to" symbol became a single horizontal bar in the US and some other countries?

Comment: @sawa: You have it completely reversed.  Why did the single equal sign become a double one in C?

Comment: @tchrist It recalls me of the often-seen uncomfort claimed by people (especially mathematicians) with having '=' as assignment and '==' as equality. So the answer to this question is given by ikegami. And the next question is: why did '=' and '==' become as is instead of keeping '=' as equality and ':=' as assignment?

Comment: @sawa => many features of Perl are Huffman coded (that is to say, common operations are shorter than uncommon ones).  `=` is used for assignment, and `==` for equality because assignment in Perl is a more common action than testing for equality.

Comment: @Eric I thought someone is going to say that. That also answers the original question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why would it have two? There's only one in `<=`, `>=` and `!=`. It's not inconsistent at all. Only `==` is inconsistent, and that's to avoid conflicts with the assignment operator.

Answer (score 16):

The spaceship operator is a combination of `a < b`, `a == b`, and `a > b`.  Presumably, the single equals sign was chosen for the same reason it was chosen for `>=` and `<=` -- it's simply shorter and easier to read.